# Returning date range of overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario where I have a SQL table that looks like the below screenshot. Is it possible to retrieve the start and end date of just the portion that overlaps between multiple records?  I've reviewed similar questions from StackOverflow, and what I found was finding the records that has overlaps, but not the actual overlap range.

The desired result will show that the start date is 1/1/2017 and the end date is 6/30/2017 since that range is in both records.

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySql? Oracle? Are there only two records in the table? If not, how do you want to handle potential multiple overlaps?

Comment: `MAX` year start and `MIN` year end perhaps?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Shall we guess the data types of the pixels or could you add DDL? Would you like a picture of a query or shall we agree to use text for DDL, data and queries?

Comment: And are you looking for a single overlap? Or multiple if there are more rows? Your sample data might be too simple.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use variables to keep it simple.  I assume you're using some join of two rows in your table where the ON condition determines that the dates overlap.  But, since the part you're asking about is displaying the overlapping dates, we can just use variables:

```
DECLARE @start1 date = '20160701', @end1 date = '20170630'
       ,@start2 date = '20170101', @end2 date = '20171231'

SELECT CASE WHEN @start2 >= @start1 THEN @start2 ELSE @start1 END AS startdate
    ,  CASE WHEN @end2   <= @end1   THEN @end2   ELSE @end1   END AS enddate
```

If you're on Azure SQL where GREATEST and LEAST are supported you can use:

```
SELECT GREATEST(@start1, @start2) AS startdate
    ,  LEAST(@end1, @end2)        AS enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to understand the logic on the overlap.

1. if we are searching for the overlap period of many rows then it will ALWAYS start at the MAX(startDate).
2. the end point will be the minimum of the end dates where it is larger than our start date.

But we need to think about checking if they have an overlap period or not.

So the code should be:

```
declare @start datetime = (select MAX(PlanYearStart) start from @t);

if exists(select PlanYearEnd from @t where PlanYearEnd<@start)
begin
    select null OverlapStart, null OverlapEnd;
    return;
end;

select 
    @start OverlapStart,
    MIN(PlanYearEnd) OverlapEnd
from @t;
```